# Quickbooks and pyodbc LIKE pattern matching

Tags: pyodbc, quickbooks

I'm using pyodbc to run some queries against Quickbooks and having some issues with pattern matching, specifically with square bracket wildcards. I don't even know if I'm allowed to use square bracket wildcards or where I would go to find that answer. The pyodbc docs don't show any examples using them from what I can see. The only wildcard that seems to work that I've tried is %.

I'm trying to build a pattern to match on these two strings:

- M-100
- J-100

This is the query that is returning no rows:

`cursor.execute("SELECT ListID,FullName from ItemInventoryAssembly WHERE Name LIKE ?", '[MJ]-100')`

These queries do return rows:

`cursor.execute("SELECT ListID,FullName from ItemInventoryAssembly WHERE Name LIKE ?", 'M-100')`

`cursor.execute("SELECT ListID,FullName from ItemInventoryAssembly WHERE Name LIKE ?", 'J-100')`

Do I have to use the following instead of [] wildcards? (I have many more names to match on and this query would end up being very long and ugly.)

`cursor.execute("SELECT ListID,FullName from ItemInventoryAssembly WHERE Name LIKE ? OR Name LIKE ?", ('M-100','J-100'))`

Additionally, where would I go to find which wildcards I'm allowed to use in my setup with pyodbc and Quickbooks?

Comment: Is this QuickBooks for WINDOWS, or QuickBooks ONLINE?

Comment: Quickbooks Desktop.